# Law of conservation of momentum and force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, momentum

It is said that internal forces do not change the state of rest to motion only external forces can change it. But in case of a gun, a gun applies force internally to the bullet inside it and the bullet changes its state from rest to motion. So how does bullet moves if internal forces do not cause motion?

Comment: What about what happens to the gun? Did you consider the recoil of it?

Comment: what exactly does "internal force" here mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you can talk about internal vs external forces you must first define the system.

If the gun plus the bullet is the system, then, neglecting gravity and assuming no one is holding the gun, then there will be no external forces acting on the system. This means that the center of mass of the system will not move, though the gun (by recoil), bullet, bullet shell, and particles of the gun powder that are released, etc., will each individually undergo motion.

If, on the other hand, the bullet alone is the system, then the gun is the external force acting on the bullet which, per Newton's third law, will be equal and opposite to that force the bullet acts on the gun.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

There is a recoil that pushes the gun back. Then, the gun holder applies force to keep the gun from moving back. So, if your system is comprised of the gun and the bullet, it is the gun holder who applies the external force. If the system is comprised of the holder, the gun, and the bullet, then it is the earth that creates the external force via the friction between the person's shoes and the floor. You can continue these sort of games by redefining what you mean by system.

Answer (score 1):

For now, let's assume that the gun were to fire in free space such that you're not holding it -- it just fires on its own.

If you consider the gun + bullet system, momentum will certainly be conserved. With guns, there is something called a recoil. As the bullet leaves the chamber forward, then gun will actually kick back, and move in the opposite direction as the bullet did. The reason that the bluet can achieve such a high speed and the gun doesn't is due to their masses -- the bullet is a lot smaller, so for momentum to be conserved, it will get a higher velocity.

Now, suppose you consider a system of just the bullet. In that case, momentum is not conserved, because the bullet is accelerated in the gun. But, the gun is not part of your system. So momentum of the bullet system won't be conserved.

Next, suppose that you are in free space, and just fired the gun (s you are holding onto it). If you consider the gun + bullet system, momentum will not be conserved, because you apply a force on the gun. However, momentum will be conserved in the you + gun + bullet system.

Lastly, suppose you fire the gun while standing on earth. Well now, given that the earth's static friction is exerting a force on you, the momentum will be conserved for the earth + you + gun + bullet system. Of course, in situations where momentum is not conserved, you could use conservation of momentum by accounting for the external forces.

It's also worth noting that momentum may be conserved along one axis but not another. For instance, if an object is falling under gravity in the $y$ direction and is struct by another object, although the 2 object system is acted upon by gravity, gravity only acts in the $y$ direction; this means that momentum in the $x$ direction will be conserved for the 2 object system.

The takeaway is that what qualifies as internal or external forces are determined by what you chose to be in your system.

Answer (score 0):

The exact statement is:

> Given of objects, the forces internal to the system can never change the state of motion of the centre of mass.

A perfect example for this is the case a bomb explosion in air. Even though the shells of the bomb scatters arround but centre of mass keeps following the it's original path and state of motion.

A proof of this can be found over [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_mass).